# How to disallow site wide access but only allow certain urls to be accessed by public via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Via htaccess, I would like to:

1 - Disallow everyone to access the site.

2 - Allow only 3 ips to pass through the ip ban.

3 - Leave 1 directory accessible fully to the public.

I understand the the rule number 3 goes against rule number 1, and this is where I am confused.

Currently I have this code:

```
<Files 403.shtml> 
order deny,allow 
deny from all 
</Files> 
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx #Fred 
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #Ben
```

The above code works fine in not letting anyone in apart from my 3 coworkers.

```
<Directory /printing/>
 Order Allow, Deny 
 Allow from All
</Directory>
```

The above code (when added) give me a 500 internal server error.

How to have a mix of both code so people can still access my directory publicly while blocking access to any other parts of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a `<Directory>` container inside an htaccess file, since htaccess is *already* per-directory.

What you need to do is create an htaccess file in the `printing` directory with just:

```
Order Allow, Deny 
Allow from All
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not think about that one!